# A property related to representations of a number in prime bases

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

Assuming that $n>0$, let $t_b(n)$ denote the base-$b$ representation of a natural number $n$, i.e. the tuple $$(d_k, d_{k-1}, \ldots, d_1, d_0)$$ such that $$n=d_kb^k+d_{k-1}b^{k-1}+\ldots+d_1b+d_0,$$ where $0 < d_k < b$ and $0 \le d_i < b$ for $i=0, 1, \ldots, k-1.$

Let $f(T)$ denote the number of different elements in a tuple $T$. For example, if $T = (2, 4, 0, 3, 1, 0)$, we have $f(T) = 5.$

Let $r(n)$ denote the largest prime $p$ such that the size of $t_p(n)$ is not less than $p$. For example, for $2^1 \le n < 3^2$ we have $r(n) = 2$, for $3^2 \le n < 5^4$ we have $r(n) = 3$, for $5^4 \le n < 7^6$ we have $r(n) = 5$, etc.

The function $g(n)$ is defined as follows: $$g(n) = \min (f(t_2(n))/2, f(t_3(n))/3, \ldots, f(t_P(n))/P, f(t_{r(n)}(n))/r(n)),$$ where $2, 3, \ldots, P$ are primes less than $r(n)$.

Let $S_x$ denote the set such that for any $n \in S_x$ we have $r(n)=x.$

Question 1: given the value of $x$, what is the value of $$h(x) = \max(g(n) : n \in S_x)?$$

Question 2: given the value of $x$, is there an efficient way to find at least one number $y \in S_x$ such that $g(y) = h(x)?$

Comment: Question 3: where do  these questions come from? They seem artificial when lacking context. It might help to explain in words what the point of something like $g(n)$ is.

Comment: @KConrad: the point of $g(n)$ is some measure of how "rich" a number can be if we look at its representation in different bases. The point of $r(n)$ is give a reasonable upper bound for the bases.

Comment: I don’t know what idea you have in mind with that description of $g(n)$, so it still looks like an uninteresting function to me.